# Problem with python-mode.el install

Tags: python, emacs, python-mode

I just installed python-mode.el (6.0.1) and when I start up Emacs.app it gives me the following error:

```
File error: Cannot open load file, highlight-indentation
```

Are there dependencies for python-mode.el that I have to install first?

Comment: How did you install? source? marmalade?

Comment: Source. I just downloaded it from the launchpad site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python-mode 6.0.1 [tar.gz bundle](http://launchpad.net/python-mode/trunk/6.0.1/+download/python-mode.el-6.0.1.tar.gz) does include highlight-indentation.el. It appears that this file was added in version 6.0. However, this is not mentioned in the README or NEWS files.